# Java connectivity issue

Tags: java, mysql

I am getting following error.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last
>   packet successfully received from the server was 37,787,544
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   37,787,544 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured
>   value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or
>   testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing
>   the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the
>   Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this
>   problem.

Once I restart the application, it works OK for some time and then the same error comes up.

Comment: I assume your question is "how do I fix this?".  Did you try the suggestions in the error message?  Are you using pooling?  Have you checked for hung connections?

Comment: Um, that timeout setting is over 10 hours.  How long is "some time"?

Comment: @bdares, where do you see what "wait_timeout" is set to?

Comment: @bdares I guess default wait_timeout is 8hrs -- 28800 secs. And it's inactive since last 10 hrs.

Comment: Er yeah.  I meant that the timeout setting would have to be over 10 hours for the connection to not die after that much idle time...

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do,

1. configure wait_timeout to a very long value a day or two. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)
2. Appenf autoReconnect=true in your MySQL connection URL `jdbc:mysql://yourhost:port/dbname?autoReconnect=true`

Answer (score 0):

Your connections are expiring because you're creating them and keeping them "forever".

The best approach is to use a connection pool, such as [Apache's DBCP - DataBase Connection Pool](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/).

One of the things a pool gives you is it checks the validity of the connection before giving it to you - if the connection is "no good" (it runs a simple query to assert this), it closes it and creates a new one then give you the new one. This neatly caters for expiration.